# How to check index of combobox based on string?

Tags: c#, combobox, indexing

I have a ComboBox with 3 hardcoded string values:

```
A
B
C
```

If I try to change the currently selected value based on `SelectedValue`, `SelectedItem`, or `SelectedText`, neither of them change the index to the proper item.

Currently I'm doing something like:

```
switch (str)
{
    case 'A':
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        break;
    case 'B':
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
        break;
    case 'C':
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 2;
        break;
}
```

But as you can see it's a rather weak solution and will break if items are re-ordered, edited, or appended.

Any better ways?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this:

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = comboBox.Items.IndexOf("B");
```

but this also works on my computer:

```
comboBox.SelectedItem = "B";
```

There must be a problem with your strings that are hardcoded in the comboBox. Check if there are some unusual characters or white (blank) characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
 List<string> values = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
 comboBox.SelectedIndex = values.FindIndex(x => x == str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but this doesn't sometimes works well:

```
comboBox.Items.IndexOf("B");
```

So I had to do this instead:

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = comboBox.FindStringExact("B");
```

Which works perfectly fine, especially if I am binding it to a list of class entities and not just strings.